# If "AQUARIUMS" is coded as "CCKOSTUWW", then what is the code for "BARBIEQUE"?

Tags: puzzle

The following question was asked in an online assessment by Goldman Sachs, for Engineering undergrads.

> If "AQUARIUMS" is coded as "CCKOSTUWW", then what is the code for "BARBIEQUE"?
>
> 1. DCTDKGSWG
> 2. CDGKSTWDG
> 3. CDDGGKSTW
> 4. DCGKSTWDG

I tried solving it in the following way:

1. First, I spilt up the word Aquariums from the middle in 2 halves.
2. Next, I found out that each letter in coded word is replaced by it's second sucessor (accoording to English alphabets).

```
     A Q U A | R | I U M S    [initial codeword]
     C C K O | S | T U W W 
     ^ ^ ^ ^   ^   ^ ^ ^ ^
     A A I M | Q | R S U U    [codeword after rearrangement]
```

However, using this logic, I couldn't deduce any meaningful soultion that would match the given options.

Comment: I appreciate the humor behind the word BARBIEQUE. Poor doll...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the letters alphabetically:

$$BARBIEQUE\to ABBEEIQRU$$

Now replace each letter with the letter two places forward ($A\to C, B\to D\ldots$):

$$ABBEEIQRU\to CDDGGKSTW$$

so the right answer is $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: I'd code AQUARIUM as AAIMQRUU and then compare it with CCKOSTUWW as it has a similar form using lexicographic order.